# Linking VLC build to ffmpeg build libraries

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, linker, vlc

I'm receiving the following error message when attempting to build VLC:

`checking for mad_bit_init in -lmad... yes
checking for MPG123... yes
checking for libavutil variant... libav
checking for GST_APP... yes
checking for GST_VIDEO... yes
checking for AVCODEC... no
configure: error: Requested 'libavcodec >= 57.16.0' but version of libavcodec is 56.1.0. Pass --disable-avcodec to ignore this error.`

I am running the command (first step of Configuration from link below, I did the contrib method and built everything else as well):
`./configure`

So let's get the obvious out of the way: I'm missing the most recent version of libavcodec (v57). Using `--disable-avcodec` is not a viable solution. Doing a quick `apt-file search libavcodec` I'm seeing that for debian/jessie the latest version published is libavcodec56, not 57. I did also notice that libavcodec57 was available for installation with ffmpeg here `https://ffmpeg.org/download.html`

I actually needed to also build ffmpeg from source. So I did that, worked my way through the dependencies without too much trouble using the guide linked to below.

So here is my issue: After building and doing a make install of ffmpeg, I still get that error above, despite having the latest libavcodec freshly compiled.

So my question is: since I used that guide, I am still getting the error when building vlc. I see that the lib exists her: `/root/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a`, and I figured `make install` would put it where it needs to be. **Is there some other compile flag I can set while compiling vlc to point it to that lib directory to look for libavcodec?**

ffmpeg build: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu
vlc build: https://wiki.videolan.org/UnixCompile/

---

UPDATE: tried this, still getting the error message: `PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/root/ffmpeg_build/lib:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH" LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/root/ffmpeg_build/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ./configure`

---

UPDATE2: tried this, still getting the error message: `./configure --libdir="/root/ffmpeg_build/lib:$LIBDIR"`

---

UPDATE3: I tried merging my ffmpeg libs into my vlc libs and may have made things worse. My ffmpeg libs lived here: /root/ffmpeg_build/lib
My vlc build (contrib builds as well) lived here: /opt/vlc/

So I merged them with my existing vlc contrib lib:
`cp /root/ffmpeg_build/lib/* /opt/vlc/contrib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/
cp /root/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig/* /opt/vlc/contrib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/pkgconfig/`

Then ran configure:
`./configure --with-contrib=contrib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Which finally worked, but now I get this error when I try to make:

Now I get the error:
`` /usr/bin/ld: /opt/vlc/contrib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libavformat.a(allformats.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `ff_a64_muxer' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC ``

Comment: Check the 'contrib' topic here : https://wiki.videolan.org/UnixCompile/

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. No solution yet? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046059/newly-built-libavcodec-not-recognized-in-ubuntu-16-04